# How can I keep my gold safe from other PCs?

Tags: dnd-5e, treasure

I play in a group that likes to steal each other's stuff constantly, and by looting/stealing from other players, I have accumulated 1008 gold pieces. My GM does not really care about the weight of money, but I would prefer not to lose it. I was wondering if there was any way for me to store the gold to keep it from the other PCs.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Hey, what class are you playing and at what level? There are solutions that work for different classes at different levels. Wizard in particular has many options.

Comment: How your DM handles stealing? That will allow answers to better refined how to guard your gold. Simple sleight of hand contest? Only when other character is sleeping? When traveling? How often this is done?

Comment: Is theft among the party something you all agreed was acceptable for the game? Do you and the other players have fun allowing this theft at the table?

Comment: The title question clearly belongs on [bitcoin.se]. 

Comment: How easily should gold be accessible *to you*?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Convert the gold to gems.

Then sew the gems into the seams and lining of your clothing.

Harder to get to without waking you up. If someone wakes you up while they are trying to rob you, welcome them to Stabbytown.  Show no mercy.

#### Alternative solution:

Have a talk with the other players and confirm that this form of PvP (stealing from other PC's) is how you *all* want to have fun.  If so, invest in needle and thread.

<sub>I originally phrased this as  "Stop playing with this group of jerks." A few of the comments pointed out that if everyone at the table is fine with mutual larceny there's no harm done.  [Stealing from one's fellow characters](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/110123/22566) is a play style that goes back to proto-D&D as played by its creators: [*Not much PvP per se, but very MUCH "uneasy alliances between ruthless pirates."*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/110123/22566)</sub>

Comment: the only question is if _you_ have fun with this. If no, leave, even if _they_ like  it.

Comment: @András That sort of what I was trying to get at with "all"

Answer (score 11):

### Gold or platinum garters

A simple non-magical solution I've used is to make or purchase gold or platinum rings of solid metal that fit snugly on the PC's upper arm, or even better their thigh.  These are nigh impossible to steal.

Make sure they are solid metal, not a chain, as chains are easier to break and remove from the body. And of course, don't tell the other players or PCs that you've done this. Only the GM need know.

### Investments and banks

As you accumulate more wealth you may want to consider placing your holdings into investments that are far more difficult to steal, such as land, buildings in a town, a castle or a keep of some sort.  A reputable bank is also a good option if there are banks in the world you adventure in.

Comment: This is historically an important function of precious-metal jewelry, though it's less viable in the typical D&D world where you need pounds and pounds of gold to buy anything.

Comment: @markwells True, though the OP currently only has 1008 gp which is only about 100 pp and that could esily be melted down to a solid thigh/arm garter or two depending on what the GM allows. Four garters are easy to manage and even 8 or more are doable. Beyond that investments in land etc. become more viable.

Comment: How do you pay for something once you have a single big chunk of gold/platinum?

Comment: @ MatthieuM. You keep what you think you'll need as coins. Everything else you convert.  In the specific situation of this OP, if you then find yourself without enough coin, well that's easy... Steal what you need from your best friend.

Comment: @MatthieuM.- Cut or shave off pieces of the appropriate weight.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacksilver

Comment: @davesherohman That's brilliant. Probably easier with gold than with platinum. Not sure if platinum  can be shaved. Is there any precedence for that in real life or D&D?

Comment: @lightcat - In real life, it was primarily done with silver ("hack silver", as documented in the wikipedia article I linked earlier) because silver was the primary medium of exchange. In a D&D world where gold and platinum predominate, there's no clear reason why it wouldn't be done with those metals. Pure platinum is nearly as soft as pure gold, so clipping/shaving it should be possible.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, it seems to me like your group is very willing to play with PVP, which is kind of unique for D&D groups. To reflect some of the other answers, this play style may or may not break your game eventually, and you may benefit from being a bit more cooperative in your games. However, it seems that you enjoy this style of play, and for that I would highly recommend playing a game of Paranoia for some over-the-top comedic backstabbing and PVP.

To actually answer your question, I would offer two solutions.

1. First of all, you could invest in something expensive that fills a
   character-specific niche. If the other players in your group can't
   make use of it, they might be less likely to take a single item than
   a large horde of gold. Of course, they may try to sell your item,
   but at least watching a single item is easier than protecting all of
   that gold.
2. If you are a heavy magic user you probably won't be asking this
   question, but on the off chance that you are a ranger or other
   applicable character, you might want to learn the spell Alarm. The
   spell itself is low-level, doesn't require much in materials, and
   should protect you without fail. You should be able to customize
   your alarm field to only permit yourself, and place it in a small
   enough area that it won't be triggered through an accident.

With that, I bid you good luck.

Comment: You said two solutions. Did I guess right on how you intended to separate them in that run on paragraph?  If not, please edit again to clear that up.