# If I am sleeping clutching on to something, how easy is it to steal that item?

Tags: dnd-5e, sleep

If when we go to sleep and the bard wants to steal the item from me while I am clutching it in my sleep, holding it to myself, how easy would it be for them to steal it from, what kind of rolls would be needed here?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. While this is a valid question, if you're worried about party members stealing from you while you're sleeping, there are bigger problems in your group dynamic that are probably worth asking about directly.

Comment: Have you asked your DM about this?  Are you the DM?  I don't think we are getting the whole story here. What problem are you trying to solve?  Also, rhetorically, why can't I give more than +1 to V2Blast's comment? ;-)  related [Q&A here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/141754/22566)

Comment: This is exactly the situation described in Matt Colville's video [The Wangrod Defense](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JoYR3eCFqoA).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the bard is trying to steal something from you in your sleep, generally the way I as a DM would run this is first they would have to make a stealth roll contested by your passive perception to see if they can get near your character without waking them. This would then be followed by a sleight of hand check for the actual theft. **Sleight of Hand** is listed on **page 177** of the players handbook as a check used to

> “lift a coin purse off another person or slip something out of their
>   pocket”

making it the skill that best matches the situation you describe. The difficulty challenge is up to your DM but generally the thresholds set by the players handbook on **page 174** is:

- Very easy - DC 5
- Easy - DC 10
- Medium - DC 15
- Hard - DC 20
- Very Hard - DC 25
- Nearly impossible - DC 30

Factors affecting your DM’s decisions should include size, weight and how noisy the object might be when moved.

However, I would ask how you as a player feels about having your possessions stolen by another player. It is general convention (at least at my table and a lot of the questions I see on this and other sites about my guy syndrome. For [example](https://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/7uwyhh/i_hate_my_players_pc/), this rant is a little long but encapsulates some of the issues that parties screwing each other over can cause) that stealing from other players can lead to bad feeling among the party. It may be worth talking to the player or your DM about how this is going to affect the dynamic at the table before this goes ahead.

Comment: Note that if you're sleeping with your eyes closed, you should have disadvantage on all Perception checks, including to detect someone sneaking up on you.

Comment: Passive perception isn’t an active check though. Its designed to represent when you aren't actively searching. As below says you can reduce passive perception by 5 to represent disadvantage.

Comment: Shouldn't "clutching" make it more difficult than just picking a pocket? I'd think you'd have disadvantage on the perception but advantage against or high-DC on the sleight of hand.

Comment: Well the dm would choose the dc of the check. I would assume a high dc for pulling something from someones hand, however the dm’s decision is what matters in this case

Comment: The only problem I have with this answer is that when one is sleeping one is unconscious, and thus the unconscious condition applies.  (Appendix A).   I'd suggest folding that mechanical detail into your (otherwise well organized and thought out) answer.

Comment: sorry, I was referring to the this [on page 172 of the basic rules](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf#page=172) the text in PHB is the same.

Comment: I wouldn't say you should have disadvantage on that perception check due to eyes being closed as it's less to do with seeing them coming and more *hearing* them coming @MarkWells

Comment: @Himitsu_no_Yami Right, but it's still harder to detect someone by hearing alone than by sight and hearing.

Comment: I think the problem from the comments and my own research from the rules stems from how you define sleep. If we define it as being unconscious as KorvinStarmast suggests, then no stealth check would need to be made as an unconscious creature is “unaware of its surroundings” (PHB page 292). However, I don’t lean to this argument personally as a loud noise would wake a sleeping character. As for being unable to see, I would respond that an invisible creature can still be detected by noise it makes (PHB 291) in which case I would stay with the minus 5 modifier to passive perception.

Answer (score 1):

### RAW, It depends how perceptive you are

To steal something from you, the bard would make a Dexterity ([Sleight of Hand](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#SleightofHand)) check [contested](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#Contests) by your [Passive](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#PassiveChecks) [Perception](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#Perception). Your Perception check would likely be made at disadvantage (-5 to a passive check) since you are asleep. Therefore, how difficult it is to steal something from you is (by RAW) entirely based on how perceptive your character is.

### There are bigger issues

That said, stealing from another player is something that varies from table to table. It is something that should be discussed in session zero. It should also be discussed if and when if become an issue as the table. As [V2Blast brilliantly puts it in the comments on your question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/153698/if-i-am-sleeping-clutching-on-to-something-how-easy-is-it-to-steal-that-item#comment399303_153698):

> While this is a valid question, if you're worried about party members stealing from you while you're sleeping, there are bigger problems in your group dynamic that are probably worth asking about directly.

If this is something that bothers you - in fact, even if it doesn't, but is happening at your table - I suggest you discuss it with the DM and other players to reach an agreement that everyone feels comfortable with.